# Reading URL's from csv und open with selenium

Tags: selenium, csv, url

I want to read out a csv file with URL's and put them into a selenium webdriver command (one by one). The addresses are all in one column in the csv. I managed to loop through the URL's with no problem. However, I can't make it work with the webdriver. It always returns to me with the same error message "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument", even if the print of the URL's looks fine. The only funny thing is, when I copy and paste the URL address from the print comamand in my editor it shows with a leading blank: ' http://[url].com'. I tried to remove the space with strip, but that had no effect on the printout. After hours of trying I feel pretty lost with this.

I use the following code:

```
with open('urls.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as read_obj:
reader = reader(read_obj)
   for row in reader:
   URL = "'" + str((row[0])) + "'"
   print(URL)
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.headless = True
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
   driver.get(URL)
driver.quit()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the point of this line: `URL = "'" + str((row[0])) + "'"` ?

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Its purpose is to create a string that can be used in the driver.get function. Anyway, I found a way to get want I want, but it took more code to do so. See the code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
source = 'myfile.csv'
with open(source, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as cp_csv:
cp_url = csv.reader(cp_csv)
for row in cp_url:
    url = row[0]
    contents.append(links)

for url in contents:
    driver.get(url)
    #do something here
driver.quit()
```